# Javascript alert window doesn't show up after a successful ajax call

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to send an alert window after the user successfully sends the email but it's not showing up. I've tried using both cookies and ajax success:, but neither strategy has worked. It sends the email successfully to the server, but the window just refreshes and no actual alert window pops up to alert the user that the email was sent. The code below is the javascript function that is in charge of sending the email.

```
function validateForm() {
  if ($('input[name=name]').val() !== "" || $('input[name=email]').val() !== "" || $('input[name=subject]').val() !== "" || $('textarea[name=message]').val() !== "") {
    formData = {
      'name': $('input[name=name]').val(),
      'email': $('input[name=email]').val(),
      'phone': $('input[name=phone]').val(),
      'subject': $('input[name=subject]').val(),
      'message': $('textarea[name=message]').val()
    };
    $.ajax({
      url: "../mail.php",
      type: "POST",
      data: formData,
      success: function(response) {
        alert(response.success);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show how you return your success data (php side) ?

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: check `console.log({response});`

Comment: If the window refreshes, you might not actually be sending the request via ajax but the form actually submits. Are you using a normal submit button which calls this function? If yes, check that you disabled the default event handler, otherwise it will not do the request via ajax

Comment: i.e. if you have `validateForm` directly bound to form `submit` or submit button `click`, `return false` at the end of it (not inside success handler) should do the trick. Alternately, see [`Event.preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)